# How to auto update node attributes in ne04j after a specific time period

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to update an existing attribute in a node to a new value after a specific time period passes ?

For example:
Node 'Offer' has the below attributes

1. Offer Name (String)
2. Offer ID (Numeric)
3. CREATED_ON (Timestamp)
4. IS_VALID ('Yes'/'No')

Process:

1. When an initial "Offer" is created IS_VALID value is "Yes"
2. After 7 days of creation IS_VALID value should be set to "No" automatically for each of the offers

I know that there is TTL , but I don't want my node to be deleted after 7 days, rather the attribute to be updated to "No" from "Yes"

Is there any way I can achieve this in Neo4j?

Comment: What about **not** storing this `is_valid` property and let the client application decide? Is that an option?

Comment: @fbiville It might be an inefficient approach, imagine fetching the non-valid offers everytime.

Comment: Let me rephrase: let the application run (in **pseudo**-Cypher) `MATCH (offer:Offer) WHERE TIMESTAMP() < offer.created_on + 7 days RETURN offer`. The application fetches only the valid offers that way and you do not need to store any `is_valid` field for that.

Comment: @fbiville - not storing is_valid was the first option I considered, but this attribute is also being used for some other purposes and it's just not for displaying offers on a page, hence couldn't use this way

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apoc` procedure calls for scheduling background jobs. `apoc.periodic.schedule()` makes sense in your case.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.schedule('offerValidater', 
"MATCH (n: Offer) WHERE apoc.date.currentTimestamp() - n.CREATED_ON > 604800000 SET n.IS_VALID = 'No'", 
86400)
```

Here I assumed that `offer.CREATED_ON` is in epoch milliseconds. If you are using other format timestamps you need to do a comparison accordingly. `offerValidater` routine is scheduled to run with a delay of 86400 seconds (1 day).

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, this looks feasible but there is a catch here. If the new offer is created on Jan-27-2021 10:15, the offer should be valid only until  Feb-3-2021 10:15. Delay of 1 day might not be feasible here and I would have to go for an hourly delay. And even then there is a chance that some of the offers might be valid for more than 7 days.

Comment: @Vader.219k Yes of course. If we are adding offers at the same time every day then 24 hrs thing works. If you want to have it in real-time doing it from the client's side is good. Maybe every time you read ``Offer`` data, you update the entries and return the fresh ones. This again has its cons. You need every client reading the offer data perform such a query.

Comment: @Vader.219k In that case, you can have another field ``valid_time``, and do ``apoc.date.currentTimestamp() - n.CREATED_ON > n.valid_time``